# How to pass lists of data from flask to JS?

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, jinja2

I have a set of lists in my python Flask server, namely `c_data`, `data`, `targetx`, `targety`, `sizex` and `sizey`. They look something like the following:

```
c_data:  ['{"pencil":[[{"startx":183,"starty":165,"endx":183,"endy":167,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":183,"starty":167,"endx":187,"endy":169,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":187,"starty":169,"endx":188,"endy":171,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":188,"starty":171,"endx":190,"endy":172,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":190,"starty":172,"endx":190,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":190,"starty":174,"endx":191,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":191,"starty":174,"endx":191,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"}]],"line":[],"rectangle":[],"circle":[],"eraser":[],"last_action":[0]}']
data:  ['data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.......(basically a very long string of base64 encoding)]
targetx:  [369]
targety:  [252]
sizex:  [100]
sizey:  [100]
```

(The `c_data` is declared in the js file as `canvas_data = {"pencil": [], "line": [], "rectangle": [], "circle": [], "eraser": [], "last_action": [] };`, this may help you understand the structure of `c_data` better)

How do I pass these lists so that I can then read them again in JS?

Here's what I tried, in the `app.py` file, I first did the following to send the data to the scripts:

```
c_data = json.dumps(c_data)
data = json.dumps(data)
targetx = json.dumps(targetx)
targety = json.dumps(targety)
sizex = json.dumps(sizex)
sizey = json.dumps(sizey)

return jsonify({'result': 'success', 'c_data': c_data, 'data': data, 'targetx': targetx, 'targety': targety, 'sizex': sizex, 'sizey': sizey})
```

and I pass it to Jinja by rendering HTML, and I also have a function in JavaScript called `pencil()`, using which I tried something like this:

```
<body onload="pencil(`{{ c_data }}`, `{{ data }}`, `{{ targetx }}`, `{{ targety }}`, `{{ sizex }}`, `{{ sizey }}`)">
```

and in my **script.js**, I used the passed data in the following way to read them:

```
async function loadImages(c_data, data, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight) {
    c_data = c_data.replace(/'/g, '"');
    data = data.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetX = targetX.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetY = targetY.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetWidth = targetWidth.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetHeight = targetHeight.replace(/'/g, '"');

    c_data = JSON.parse(c_data);
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    targetX = JSON.parse(targetX);
    targetY = JSON.parse(targetY);
    targetWidth = JSON.parse(targetWidth);
    targetHeight = JSON.parse(targetHeight);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var tx = parseInt(targetX[i]);
        var ty = parseInt(targetY[i]);
        var tw = parseInt(targetWidth[i]);
        var th = parseInt(targetHeight[i]);
        var img = {
            src: await loadImage(data[i], i),
            c_data: c_data[i],
            ul: {
                x: tx,
                y: ty
            },
            ur: {
                x: tx + tw,
                y: ty
            },
            ll: {
                x: tx,
                y: ty + th
            },
            lr: {
                x: tx + tw,
                y: ty + th
            }
        };
        images.push(img)
        
    }
    draw_canvas();
}
```

Using this approach, all the data works fine **except** `c_data`, which does not get converted to the `canvas_data` object type which I was expecting and has some backslashes in its string. And when I try to remove the backslashes using the line `c_data = c_data.replace(/\\/g, '');` I get the error:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4`

How do I correctly parse the above data types to JS and read them?

Comment: Why do you double convert your data to JSON format on the server side? You only need to pass your data to `jsonify`. The entire dict that is passed with all the lists it contains is converted to JSON. It is not necessary to use `json.dumps`. It seems to me that as long as you don't send an AJAX request to get the data, you should rather pass the data to `render_template` and convert with the [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson) filter.

Comment: I was going through multiple ways about how to pass data from flask to JS, and this was working for all the data types except `c_data` so I let it stay that way. What changes should I do in the `loadImages` function after removing `json.dumps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to deduce your code from your explanations.

If you omit `json.dumps` on the server, you don't have to parse the data again in the browser. This eliminates the then unnecessary calls of `JSON.parse`.

Data can be passed from Flask to JavaScript in a number of ways.

###### 1) Using the tojson filter:

One possibility is to transfer the data to the template as usual and then convert it to JSON with the Jinja filter `tojson`.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    c_data = {
        "pencil":[
            [
                {"startx":183,"starty":165,"endx":183,"endy":167,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":183,"starty":167,"endx":187,"endy":169,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":187,"starty":169,"endx":188,"endy":171,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":188,"starty":171,"endx":190,"endy":172,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":190,"starty":172,"endx":190,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":190,"starty":174,"endx":191,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":191,"starty":174,"endx":191,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"}
            ]
        ],
        "line":[],
        "rectangle":[],
        "circle":[],
        "eraser":[],
        "last_action":[0]
    }
    data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.......(basically a very long string of base64 encoding)'
    targetx = [369]
    targety = [252]
    sizex = [100]
    sizey = [100]
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      ((cData, data, targetX, targetY, sizeX, sizeY) => {

        function pencil(cData, data, targetX, targetY, sizeX, sizeY) {
          console.log(cData, data, targetX, targetY, sizeX, sizeY);
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          pencil(cData, data, targetX, targetY, sizeX, sizeY);
        });
        
      })(
        {{ c_data | tojson }},
        {{ data | tojson }},
        {{ targetx | tojson }},
        {{ targety | tojson }},
        {{ sizex | tojson }},
        {{ sizey | tojson }}
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### 2) Get data converted with jsonify:

Another possibility is to obtain the data from another endpoint via AJAX. The data is converted into JSON format on the server side using `jsonify`.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    jsonify
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data')
def data():
    c_data = {
        "pencil":[
            [
                {"startx":183,"starty":165,"endx":183,"endy":167,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":183,"starty":167,"endx":187,"endy":169,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":187,"starty":169,"endx":188,"endy":171,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":188,"starty":171,"endx":190,"endy":172,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":190,"starty":172,"endx":190,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":190,"starty":174,"endx":191,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},
                {"startx":191,"starty":174,"endx":191,"endy":174,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"}
            ]
        ],
        "line":[],
        "rectangle":[],
        "circle":[],
        "eraser":[],
        "last_action":[0]
    }
    data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.......(basically a very long string of base64 encoding)'
    targetx = [369]
    targety = [252]
    sizex = [100]
    sizey = [100]
    return jsonify(
        c_data=c_data, 
        data=data, 
        targetx=targetx, targety=targety, 
        sizex=sizex, sizey=sizey
    )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (async (uri) => {
        
        function pencil(cData, data, targetX, targetY, sizeX, sizeY) {
          console.log(cData, data, targetX, targetY, sizeX, sizeY);
        }

        const dat = await fetch(uri).then(resp => resp.json());
        const { c_data, data, targetx, targety, sizex, sizey } = dat;
        pencil(c_data, data, targetx, targety, sizex, sizey);

      })({{ url_for('data') | tojson }});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```